# What are advantages and disadvantages of a Sorcerer/Rogue multi-classed character?

Tags: dnd-5e, multi-classing, rogue, sorcerer

I have recently joined a 5e campaign and I was thinking about making a Sorcerer Rogue multi-classed character.  Before I commit to that character build, what are the pros and cons of multi-classing in the 5e stystem that apply to mixing those two classes: Sorcerer and Rogue.

Comment: This is a very broad question, but you might be interested in [this related question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/91346/15469) as a starting point.

Comment: @Miniman I have tried to scope this question more tightly with an edit.

Comment: Zack, do you have an idea of how long your group will play D&D with these characters?  Up to 5th level? Up to 11th level?  To 20th?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main disadvantage seems to be that ability score increases (ASI's) are tied to class level in 5e rather than character level, so you really need to keep your multi-class levels in multiples of 4 in order not to lose this important feature.

Spell casting is another major thing, especially for a sorcerer. If you don't multi-class with another spell caster you will lose access to spell slots, which I understand is pretty important for a Sorcerer.

Answer (score 3):

One advantage is that you will have a more varied array of options available to you.

One disadvantage is that those options will all be of a lower level than you could have had if you stuck to a single class.

If you take 10 levels of one class and 10 levels of another class you will have twice as many level 10 and level 5 class features to use, but you won't have any level 15 or level 20 class features.